# failed to precompile Gurobi (on Windows, using Julia)?

Tags: julia, atom-editor, gurobi

I am trying to run a Julia program using Gurobi solver on Windows.

I have already set up my GUROBI_HOME in windows as C:\gurobi701\win64.
Here is the error message in Atom:
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRUAm.png)

I have done the following in Julia interactive shell:

```
Pkg.add("Gurobi")
```

also

```
Pkg.update()
```

Also, I checked whether or not my gurobi license file is not properly set up by running their example:

```
> gurobi_cl C:\gurobi701\win64\examples\data\coins.lp
```

The output seems fine: [output for gurobi command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4GVf.png)

What is the possible error here? 
Thanks a lot for help!!!

Comment: what happens if you comment the first line of [Gurobi.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/blob/master/src/Gurobi.jl)? do note that editing your library files is unwise practice. however, it could fix the precompilation issue.